# XX:OnOutOfMemoryError on setenv.sh

Tags: jvm, out-of-memory, tomcat5.5

i want to set a script which will restart the server automatically.

And i write the following code to `setenv.sh` file

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-5.5.30/bin/shutdown.sh;/usr/local/apache-tomcat-5.5.30/bin/startup.sh;"
```

It not working properly.
I am using `tomcat 5`.

Comment: What do you mean by not working properly?  Can you give a specific error?

Comment: I am unable to restart the tomcat when OutOfMemoryError occure

Comment: What error do you get?  Is there a message in the logs somewhere?

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space  This 2 error getting at-least in a day. And then i get http 500 error and then it tell me system is not accessible. And tomcat goes down

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question - I don't think the error handler can run several commands. If you want to do this, then write a small restart script and run your custom script.

However, I would think about this again. Not every OutOfMemoryError means the server should be restarted automatically. You'd better to get a notification and then profile the server to get the cause of the OOME, so you can get rid of it.

P.S
Any reason to use the old tomcat 5.5? tomcat 7 is quite mature.

Comment: Hi thanks for help. can you tell me one thing we have 2 GB ram and our tomcat goes down at-least 1 time in a day. Only 50 user using it at a time.  Can you help me?

Comment: First of all, check if the OOME of the heap or of the perm gen (it's in the log). If you an stand a few minutes of downtime (worst case) is to add the -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError flag which will give an heap dump file automatically whom you can analyse using applications such as http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

Answer (score 0):

#### Use **CATALINA_OPTS** instead

```
CATALINA_OPTS="${CATALINA_OPTS} -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\"/bin/sleep 30;/bin/kill %p; /bin/sleep 60; /bin/kill -9 %p\""
```